# I got an error while building react native app in android

Tags: react-native

I have this error:

**Error:**

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
>   'D:\reactjs2019naresh\appnaresh\assets\images'

**ERROR:**

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
>   'D:\reactjs2019naresh\appnaresh\assets\images'

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Give more context - when do you get this error? What machine are you working on? What are you trying to do?Tell as much details as possible

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. It just a npm error that i fixed it.

Comment: Sir i need one more help , How do i develop a react native android app without expo in my windows 7 o.s ?

Comment: I have answered with a guide on how you can get started without expo

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your workspace already meets these requirements -  JDK installed (with PATH variable clearly defined),   Android Studio, node + npm

So, without Expo - here is how you get started:

1. Install react-native globally using the command below:

```
    npm install -g react-native-cli
```

2. Start the react native project, like this:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

3. change directory to where your project is located then run this command:

```
react-native run-android
```

More links here:
[tutorial - a bit old](https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-on-windows-90d85a72ae65) , [another guide](https://hackernoon.com/react-native-how-to-setup-your-first-app-a36c450a8a2f) and the getting started guide from [facebook](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)